# What is the R equivalent of matlab's csaps()

Tags: r, matlab, splines

`csaps()` in matlab does a cubic spline according to a particular definition of the smoothing parameter `p`. Here is some matlab code and its result:

```
     % x variable
    age = 75:99  

    % y variable
    diffs = [-39   -2 -167  -21  -13   32  -37 -132 -143  -91  -93  -88  -62 -112  -95  -28  -90  -40  -27  -23  -28  -11   -8   -6    1]

    % 0.0005 is the parameter p, and the later specification of 
    % age are the desired x for prediction
    csaps(age,diffs,0.0005,age)
    % result (column headers removed):
     -63.4604  -64.0474  -64.6171  -65.1397  -65.6111  -66.0165  -66.3114  
     -66.4123  -66.2229  -65.6726  -64.7244  -63.3582  -61.5676  -59.3568  
     -56.7364  -53.7382  -50.4086  -46.7922  -42.9439  -38.9183  -34.7629  
     -30.5180  -26.2186  -21.8912  -17.5532
```

I'd like to get the same result in R. I've tried `base::smooth.spline()`, but the smoothing parameter `spar` is specified in a different way that I can't seem to relate to matlab's `p` (can *you*?). The closest result I've been able to get has been with the `smooth.Pspline()` function of the `pspline` package. Here is some code to get things rolling in R:

```
age <- 75:99
diffs <- c(-39L, -2L, -167L, -21L, -13L, 32L, -37L, -132L, -143L, -91L, 
-93L, -88L, -62L, -112L, -95L, -28L, -90L, -40L, -27L, -23L, 
-28L, -11L, -8L, -6L, 1L)
predict(pspline::smooth.Pspline(
                           x = age,
                           y = diffs, 
                           norder = 2, 
                           method = 1,
                           spar = 1 / 0.0005     # p given in MP and matlab as 0.0005
                         ),age)
# which gives something close, but not exactly the same:
 [1] -63.46487 -64.05103 -64.61978 -65.14158 -65.61214 -66.01662 -66.31079
 [8] -66.41092 -66.22081 -65.67009 -64.72153 -63.35514 -61.56447 -59.35372
[15] -56.73367 -53.73584 -50.40680 -46.79098 -42.94333 -38.91850 -34.76393
[22] -30.51985 -26.22131 -21.89474 -17.55757
```

The csaps() help page is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/csaps.html)

`smooth.spline()` help can be found [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/smooth.spline.html) (code not given because I think maybe the relation between `spar` and `p` is pretty hairy, so maybe not worth going down this path)

`pspline::smooth.Pspline()` help is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pspline/pspline.pdf)

This [other person's quest from 2008](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/173555.html) appears to have gone unanswered, making me feel like [this guy](http://xkcd.com/979/).

R is chock full of spline doings, so if the saavy amongst ye can point me to the one that does the same thing as matlab's `csaps()` (or a trick along those lines) I'd be most appreciative.

[EDIT 19-8-2013]
`spar` needs to be specified as `(1-p)/p`  (rather than `1/p`) and then results will agree to as far as numerical precision can take you. See answer below.

Comment: You already have a method that is in agreement to 5 decimal places (on the ratios). I fail to see the value in trying to get exact agreement to an approximation to an undefined "something".

Comment: @DWin This is a small sprocket in a big matlab -> R conversion project of some legacy code. Lots of stuff downstream depends on this, and the function is used more than once in the original code. It's important to us because downstream estimates need to be exact, as in *exact*

Comment: Exact? You just drew two splines through that set of scattered points. How can you assert that either one of them is "exact"?

Comment: @DWin yeah, it's like fingerpainting, I get it. I don't claim that either exactly represents the data. What I need is to reproduce a result *exactly*, not find the truth exactly. Task not whim. The question is valid. If it's not implemented in R then I'll make do, but I'll still fish for an answer if I may.

Comment: You should examine how sensitive the R result is to variations in "spar".

Comment: If you really must produce identical values then `edit csaps` and look at the code.

Comment: thank you DWin and horchler. Got the answer-- I needed to specify spar differently

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My colleague found the answer: One converts matlab's `p` to `pspline::smooth.Pspline()`'s `spar` not as `1/p`, but as `(1-p)/p`, and then results will agree out to whatever the degree of numerical precision is:

```
c(predict(pspline::smooth.Pspline(
                          x = age,
                          y = diffs, 
                          norder = 2, 
                          method = 1,
                          spar = (1-0.0005) / 0.0005     # p given in MP and matlab as 
                         ),age))
 [1] -63.46035 -64.04741 -64.61705 -65.13972 -65.61114 -66.01646 -66.31144
 [8] -66.41232 -66.22285 -65.67263 -64.72443 -63.35823 -61.56761 -59.35675
[15] -56.73643 -53.73821 -50.40864 -46.79221 -42.94387 -38.91828 -34.76291
[22] -30.51801 -26.21863 -21.89122 -17.55320
```

Comment: thanks, really helpfull 10Y later (there are indeed two main cubic smoothing spline algo and it was difficuly to identify the correct one in R : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221215/is-there-an-r-spline-that-matches-the-schoenberg-algorithm/75235153#75235153

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I found in p. 16 of [MATLAB/R Reference](http://www.math.umaine.edu/~hiebeler/comp/matlabR.html) by David Hiebeler. [I don't use Matlab,however].

Fit natural cubic spline(S′′(x) = 0 at both endpoints) to points (xi, yi)whose coordinates are in vectors x and y; evaluate at points whose x coordinates are in vector xx, storing
corresponding y’s in yy

**Matlab:**

```
pp=csape(x,y,’variational’);
yy=ppval(pp,xx) but note that
csape is in Matlab’s Spline
Toolbox
```

**R**

```
tmp=spline(x,y,method=’natural’,
xout=xx); yy=tmp$y
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but no dice. Looking to reproduce `csaps()`. I adapted your (Hiebeler's) R code to my problem and it doesn't do the trick.