# Is there an R spline that matches the Schoenberg algorithm?

Tags: r, smoothing, spline

Is there a R algorithm that fit smoothing splines while minimizing L,

L = **ρ** ∑ (i from 0 to n-1) wi(yi-Si(xi))² + **(1 - ρ)** ∫ (x from 0 to x_(n-1)) (S''(x))² dx

Maybe it's possible with smooth.spline but I didn't succeed to find the good parameters.

(The equation can be seen more clearly here : [https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/functionfit/SmoothingCubicSpline.html](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Esimardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/functionfit/SmoothingCubicSpline.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
pspline::smooth.Pspline(  x = input_x,
                          y = input_y, 
                          norder = 2, 
                          method = 1,
                          spar = rho)
```

will do the job.